# Xamarin Forms Carousel view issue with binding

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Hello I’m having an issue with binding a list of string to my Carousel View
First I have a list of an object I get from my server

```
public class PostObject
    {
        public string PostOwner { get; set; }
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public string ProfileImage { get; set; }
        public List<string> PostImages { get; set; }
    }
  List<PostObject> posts = new List<PostObject>();
```

This works as I expected.

Next I have a card view I created and within the card view I want to have a Carousel View.

So I have setup my Xaml like this (omitting the parts that works for clarity)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Abstractions;assembly=ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin"
              NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="True"
             NavigationPage.HasBackButton="False"
             NavigationPage.BackButtonTitle="Back"
             Title="amici"
             x:Class="amici.Posts">

    <NavigationPage.TitleView>
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" Spacing="10" >
            <Label x:Name="GroupTitle" TextColor="White" FontSize="Medium"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </NavigationPage.TitleView>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="iconexample" Icon="settings.png" Priority="0" Order="Primary" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>

    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HasUnevenRows="true"
             IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
             IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
             CachingStrategy="RecycleElement">
                <!--ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"-->
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell >
                            <StackLayout Padding="10">
                                <Frame x:Name="myframe" HasShadow="True" >

                                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0"  >
                                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <Label Grid.Row="0"  Text="{Binding PostOwner}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Font="Bold,16"  />
                                        <controls:CircleImage Grid.Row="0" Margin="10" BorderColor="white" BorderThickness="1" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Start" Source="{Binding ProfileImage}" Aspect="AspectFit">
                                            <controls:CircleImage.WidthRequest>
                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                    <On Platform="Android, iOS">65</On>
                                                </OnPlatform>
                                            </controls:CircleImage.WidthRequest>
                                            <controls:CircleImage.HeightRequest>
                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double">
                                                    <On Platform="Android, iOS">65</On>
                                                </OnPlatform>
                                            </controls:CircleImage.HeightRequest>
                                        </controls:CircleImage>

                                        <Label Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding Post}" LineBreakMode="WordWrap" Font="Bold,16"  />

                                        <CarouselView x:Name="PostImages" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding PostImages}">
                                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Image Source="{Binding .}" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                        </CarouselView>

                                        <!--<Image Grid.Row="2"  Source="{Binding ImageURL}" Aspect="AspectFill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />-->
                                        <BoxView Grid.Row="3"  BackgroundColor="black" HeightRequest="1"  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Label  Text="Likes: " LineBreakMode="NoWrap" Font="Bold,14" />
                                            <Label  Text="0" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" FontSize="14" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                                            <Label Text="Comments: " LineBreakMode="NoWrap"  Font="Bold,14"  HorizontalOptions="End" />
                                            <Label Text="0" HorizontalOptions="End"  LineBreakMode="NoWrap" FontSize="14" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                        <!--<Label Grid.Row="2" Text="{Binding OwnerFullName}" LineBreakMode="NoWrap" FontSize="16" />-->
                                    </Grid>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
         </StackLayout>


    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

In my code behind I  have this

```
public Posts (GroupInfo ginfo)
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            GroupTitle.Text = ginfo.Title;
            CurrentGroupInfo = ginfo;
            GetDataPosts();


            ItemsListView.RefreshCommand = new Command(() => {
                GetDataPosts();
                ItemsListView.IsRefreshing = false;

            });
        }

public void GetDataPosts()
        {
            try
            {
                string apikey = Application.Current.Properties["api"].ToString();
                ItemsListView.ItemsSource = null;
                posts.Clear();

                if (RestController.GetMyPostData(ref posts, CurrentGroupInfo.Id.ToString(), apikey))
                {
                    ItemsListView.ItemsSource = posts;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

        }
```

now up to this point everything works and no errors but when the app goes to render the page I get a error

**System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Xamarin.Forms.ItemsView' threw an exception.**

which I trace back to the Carousel View. When I comment out the Carousel View the it works. so I'm thinking I can't bind OR use the Carousel View in the way I thought?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.TypeInitializationException Xamarin CarouselView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56232284/system-typeinitializationexception-xamarin-carouselview)

Comment: I am not seeing any assembly reference which would include the CarouselView. Might that be the reason for your exception

Comment: @ Mouse On Mars I'm using Xamarin.Forms 3.6.0.344457 and when I go to the toolbox (Visual Studio 2017) I see the Carousel View there and that what I added to my XAML? do I still have to download and the control and add it to my assembly reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you can see the Carousel View on Xamarin.Forms 3.6.0.344457， it only defines an interface there. There're no implementations and properties in the Carousel View Class.

You can only utilize it under Xamarin.Forms 4.0. As it is still a preview version now, there're some limitations. See my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56235795/8354952 for more information.

Comment: @Mike Have you got the expected result on Xamarin.Forms 4.0 preview?

Comment: sorry for the long delay but no I decided to use a plugin for my CarouselView

Answer (score 2):

The CarouselView used to be a plugin that has now become part of Xamarin.Forms effective with version 4. You can use an earlier XF version but you will need to get this [plugin](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView), add assembly references to your XAML and put initialization code in your platform specific projects.

Alternatively, you could upgrade to Xamarin.Forms 4